# Phase line - differential equations..

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

For the differential equation:
$$
y' = y(y+2) + 4
$$
I expanded it to:
$$
y' = y^2 + 2y + 4
$$

I am asked to draw a phase line, and draw some typical solutions on the plane.
However, there is no equilibrium solution to the equation above.

Is it correct that the phase line should have a upward pointing arrow(increasing function)
for all values of y?.

Another thing is, I separated the variables but not sure if it is correct.

I get

$$
y^2 + 2y + 4 = ke^t
$$
but am unsure on how to continue..

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You face a separable differential equation. So, express $$x'=\frac{1}{y^2+2 y+4}$$ and integrate. This gives $$x=\frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{y+1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)}{\sqrt{3}}+C$$ and then $$y=\sqrt{3} \tan \left( C+\sqrt{3} x\right)-1$$